# Failed to Read Data from csv in Spark using the spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark , while trying to read data from the CSV file using the spark session , I am facing the Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelationProvider
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:42)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:263)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:342)
at ReadFromCsv$.main(ReadFromCsv.scala:22)
at ReadFromCsv.main(ReadFromCsv.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelationProvider
```

Code :

```
object ReadFromCsv {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("InputFromFile").setMaster("local")

        val session = SparkSession.builder()
                      .config(conf = conf)
                      .master("local")
                      .appName("Spark CSV Reader")
                      .getOrCreate

        val df = session.read
                 .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                 .option("header","true")
                 .csv("file.csv")

        df.createOrReplaceTempView("train")
        df.cache()
        val resultsCsvDF = session.sql("SELECT * from train ")
        resultsCsvDF.show()
    }
}
```

Library dependencies used

```
org.apache.spark :: spark-sql_2.10, spark-hive_2.10, spark-core_2.10
com.databricks :: spark-csv_2.10
```

Comment: There are two things you need to check and make sure. 1. Remember to use spark-csv library as dependency package on command line when using spark-submit/spark-shell 2. Make sure you compile and use only one scala version through out all library.

Comment: @YoungSpice scalaVersion : 2.10.4

Comment: @evan058 Yeah i have tried word count , matrix multiplication by getting the inputs from file .

Comment: @LostInOverflow

name := "ScalaSpark"

    version := "1.0"

    scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0" ,
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.5.0" ,
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.0" ,
      "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.0.0"
    )


    resolvers ++= Seq(
      "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/",
      "Maven Central" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    )

Comment: Versions of libraries you use are __completely messed up__.  All Spark modules should have the same version! In your case it is 1.5, 1.6  and 2.0 in the same application.